Can EdDSA do signature aggregation like BLS and supports batch verification
BLS is mostly used for signature aggregation and batch verification. I want to know if I can implement an EdDSA-based scheme where a single document (the same message) needs to be signed by multiple signatories as a multi-signature scheme. For batch verification, what I am suggesting is that all the public keys will be verified with the aggregated signature in a single step. (I need to know if EdDSA is capable of doing this, please guide)

Welcome to crypto-SE! For reference: batch verification is in the defining paper on EdDSA, for unrelated key/message/signature triplets.
